# Creating a spring boot app and can't get @autowired to work

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle, yaml

I've got this running and building well if I hard code my input file location, but when I try to use autowired to get the field populated it just dies and won't start the app because it can't find the bean I created. So I'll give you guys a breakdown of what I have, any feedback or ideas are welcome!

**note**
I'm running springboot version 1.4.2 because I'm using Velocity and it's not supported after that so keep that in mind as you're looking at this. Let me know if you need additional information about my set up or if you have any clarifying questions. Thanks!

Ok, here's my layout:
**application.yml**

```
atb:
  #jons directory
  inputDirectory: C:/dev/git/agenttransferbatch/src/main/resources/testinputfile.txt
  #Geoff's directory
#  inputDirectoy: C:/dev/workspaces/agenttransferbatch/src/main/resources/testinputfile.txt
spring:dataSource:
    url: jdbc:db2://pmp.shelterinsurance.com
    driverClassName: com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver
    username: myusername
    password: mypassword
```

**AppConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig
{
    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertyConfigIn() {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }

    @Bean
    public String getInputDirectory(@Value("${inputDirectory}") String inputDirectory)
    {
        return inputDirectory;
    }

    @Bean
    public ProcessController getProcessController()
    {
        return new ProcessController();
    }
}
```

**ProcessController.java**

```
@Component
public class ProcessController
{
    @Autowired
    String inputDirectory;

@PostConstruct
public void init()
{
    if(inputDirectory != null && inputDirectory.length() > 0)
    {
        processInputFile();
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("filePath is null or length 0");
    }
}

private void processInputFile()
{
    // code to process my input file is here, not relevant to this problem so won't bore you with it.
}
```

}

**AgttransApplication.java**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@Component
public class  AgttransApplication
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SpringApplication.run(AgttransApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

**file structure**

```
src
  main
    java
      com.shelter.agttrans
        configs
          AppConfig
        dataaccessobjects
          IndividualDAO
          WholesaleDAO
        dataobjects
          TransDataObject
        services
          ProcessController
        AgttransApplication
      controllers
        templates
          XMLController
    output
    resources
      application.yml
  test
  .gitignore
  build.gradle
  gradle.properties
```

**Output when it runs**

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'processController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'inputDirectory' in string value "${inputDirectory}"
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:376) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1219) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:551) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:754) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:866) ~[spring-context-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542) ~[spring-context-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:761) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:371) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1186) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1175) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at com.shelter.agttrans.AgttransApplication.main(AgttransApplication.java:13) [main/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'inputDirectory' in string value "${inputDirectory}"
    at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.parseStringValue(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:174) ~[spring-core-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.replacePlaceholders(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:126) ~[spring-core-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.doResolvePlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:219) ~[spring-core-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.resolveRequiredPlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:193) ~[spring-core-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer$2.resolveStringValue(PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.java:172) ~[spring-context-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveEmbeddedValue(AbstractBeanFactory.java:813) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1079) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1059) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:835) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:467) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1128) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1022) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:512) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:207) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1131) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1059) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:589) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:370) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    ... 16 common frames omitted
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':bootRun'.
> Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_152\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 9.061 secs
Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_152\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
10:43:28 AM: External task execution finished 'bootRun'.
```

Comment: Please Add the stacktrace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out it was nothing with my project set up. I had to hard code a dependency to our ivy repository. The default link to the ivy repository had other things involved with the process and was creating cyclical dependencies and also dependencies we didn't need for our project. This is the code we put in to hard code the ivy repository link.

```
ivy {
    url "//ourserver/Repository/ivy-thirdparty"
    layout "pattern", {
        ivy "[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[module]-[revision].xml"
        artifact "[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[artifact]-[revision](-[classifier]).[ext]"
    }
}
```

Hopefully that answer will help anyone else looking at this problem. But the code posted here is clean and will work for other setups as well if anyone needs a template.

Answer (score 2):

For Strings, you don't need to define a bean and use autowire, you can simply use the `@Value` annotation on the field:

```
@Value("${inputDirectory}")
private String inputDirectory;
```

and also, since you are using yaml, as @AHungerArtist stated, you need to use `${atb.inputDirectory}`

Comment: I tried taking the autowired out and just doing it this way and got the exact same error. It's something to do with that .yml file not being recognized. I added another application-default.yml and set the spring environment to something completely invalid and it did the same thing. It's not picking up the application.yml file as valid. I'll put my file tree in the post here so you can see my structure. Maybe it's something there.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing `@Value("${inputDirectory}")` to `@Value("${atb:inputDirectory}")` or `@Value("${atb.inputDirectory}")`.

Comment: Didn't work again. I had tried that before as well. Sorry I didn't mention that. I did leave it as that now however because as @Nir Levy said, it does need to be that way anyway. Thanks for that catch.

Comment: It did not, unfortunately.

Comment: I'm thinking that maybe spring 1.4 doesn't support .yml??? I'm trying going to the old .properties method of the resource file now. Will post if it changes anything.

Comment: Nope, that didn't help either... this is very frustrating... I've had 3 other developers be just as baffled as I am on this one. They all look at my code and don't see anything wrong outside of what you guys have pointed out. And those things are fixed now... not sure what the dang problem is.

Comment: adding it to the main text so I can use the code tags